# mostrar dato de una etiqueta con Jquery, el valor viene desde una clase Java Controller

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring-boot, jstl

Buenas tardes compañeros, soy nuevo usando Spring Boot y necesito de su apoyo por favor.

Desde mi clase controlador(@Conroller) envió datos a mi Jsp y los datos se muestran correctamente, pero al dar clic en la etiqueta anchor- no me muestra el valor de la etiqueta con clase nameproduc al usar Jquery, y me muestra el valor del div que busco reemplazar; gracias ante todo.

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 my-4 mt-md-3 mb-md-5">
                <div class="h4">Más Productos similares:</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-12 bg-shad pt-4 pb-1">
                <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme text-center" id="gallery_01">
            <!-- me muestra 12 grupos similares: -->
                    <c:forEach items="${producto}" var="producto">  
                        <a href="#" class="selecproduct item thumb-wrapper text-decoration-none" data-image="${urlPublic}/imagenes/frutas/${producto.proimagen}" data-zoom-image="${urlPublic}/imagenes/frutas/${producto.proimagen}">
                            <div class="border rounded" >
                                <img src="${urlPublic}/imagenes/frutas/${producto.proimagen}" alt="" class="">
                                <div class="nameproduc">${producto.nomProducto}</div>
                                <span class="precioproduct">${producto.precio}</span>
                                <div class="d-none">${producto.dataFilPro}</div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </c:forEach>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

 <script>
$(".selecproduct").click(function(){
        var nombPro = $(".nameproduc").html();
        alert(nombPro);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No me había dado cuenta de que el *div* está dentro del enlace.

- Dentro de la función `$(this)` hace referencia al enlace en que se hizo clic
- Solo necesitas usarlo para encontrar el resto de elementos con [`$(this).find('.clase')`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

```js
$(".selecproduct").click(function(){
    // Encontrar elemento con clase nameproduc desde el enlace
    let nombPro = $(this).find('.nameproduc').html();
    alert(nombPro);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 my-4 mt-md-3 mb-md-5">
                <div class="h4">Más Productos similares:</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-12 bg-shad pt-4 pb-1">
                <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme text-center" id="gallery_01">
            <!-- me muestra 12 grupos similares: -->
                        <a href="#" class="selecproduct item thumb-wrapper text-decoration-none">
                            <div class="border rounded" >
                                <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png" alt="" class="">
                                <div class="nameproduc">Airplane</div>
                                <span class="precioproduct">123</span>
                                <div class="d-none">Filtro 1</div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" class="selecproduct item thumb-wrapper text-decoration-none">
                            <div class="border rounded" >
                                <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/girl.png" alt="" class="">
                                <div class="nameproduc">Girl</div>
                                <span class="precioproduct">456</span>
                                <div class="d-none">Filtro 2</div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Gracias por compartir tus conocimientos, ya que obtengo el resultado que buscaba. No había visto el método find(), muchas gracias.